# Changing a Column Choice value and allowing the existing column value to remain the same when item is edited

Tags: list

Last year, when removing a choice value, the existing column value remained.  When the item was edited, the column value remained the same and was not required to be updated to a current choice value.  This year, when an item is edited, it will not allow the prior column value to remain the same, but instead, requires the editor to select a current choice value.  How can I keep the prior column value in the column?  Our items definitely need to be updated for tracking purposes.  Choice values need to be removed when a maximum total is met for each choice, but they need to remain in the items' column, as is, when edited.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable fill in choices for the column to allow old values to stay in place during editing.